# Regular Expression: optional group is not working

Tags: regex, option-type, regex-group

I have this regEx:

> \n1\s(\d{2,8})\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\w{1,10})\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\w{3}).+?Ihre
>   Art.-Nr.\s(\d+).+?(?:DeliveryDate:\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})).+?(?:ExtraCharge.+?entspricht:\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\w{1,10}))

Works fine so far. It matches something like this:

> 1 123456 25,00 Stck 100,00 2.500,00 EUR
>
> . . . some text
>
> Ihre Art.-Nr. 1690431
>
> **DeliveryDate: 21.11.2019**
>
> . . . some text
>
> incl.**ExtraCharge**
>
> **entspricht: 222,00 EUR**

Now I want the bold parts to be optional (in some cases the values are missing in the document).

My idea was to just add a questionmark to the groups:

> \n1\s(\d{2,8})\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\w{1,10})\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\w{3}).+?Ihre
>   Art.-Nr.\s(\d+).+?(?:DeliveryDate:\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}))**?**.+?(?:ExtraCharge.+?entspricht:\s(\d{0,3}(.\d{3})*,\d*)\s(\w{1,10}))**?**

but it doesn't work, and I don't know why

Comment: Can you please provide the sample run of your regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: “but it doesn't work” is not really usefull, what doesn't work? Please, give some test cases and expected result. What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(?:DeliveryDate:\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}))?` is not matched, then the regex still expects the `.+?` before and after to still match.

Try putting the ending `.+?` inside of the non-capturing group that you have for DeliveryDate. eg

`(?:DeliveryDate:\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}).+?)?`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.+?`, you could match the separate parts checking for the values at the beginning of the line using a negative lookahead `(?!`

As it seems that the money like values always end with a comma, instead of using `\d{0,3}(\.\d{3})*,\d*` which could possible also match `.123,` you could use `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+)` instead.

Assuming that `incl.` is always present, you could use that as a marker in the pattern to match at least until that part.

You could still use the optional groups for DeliveryDate and for ExtraCharge

`(?:DeliveryDate:\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}))?` and `(?:ExtraCharge\r?\n\s*entspricht:\s(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+))\s(\w{1,10}))?`

The whole pattern could look like:

```
\n1\s(\d{2,8})\s(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+))\s(\w{1,10})\s(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+))\s(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+))\s(\w{3})(?:\r?\n(?!Ihre).*)*\r?\nIhre Art.-Nr.\s(\d+)(?:\r?\n(?!DeliveryDate:|incl\.).*)*\r?\n(?:DeliveryDate:\s(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}))?(?:\r?\n(?!incl\.).*)*\r?\nincl\.(?:ExtraCharge\r?\n\s*entspricht:\s(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+))\s(\w{1,10}))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lz6H5S/1)